# customer segments based on number from .. to

Tags: customer, custom, customer-segmentation

I created a custom customer attribute which is a text field and is a numeric only field.  This is an internal attribute that is populated by some calculations and is never seen by the use.  I want to be able to use this field in a customer segment and do a range value on it for the segment.  So say the field is called rank, I want to be able make segments like so.

```
Segment 1: Rank > 0 and Rank < 100
Segment 2: Rank > 100 and Rank < 500
Segment 3: Rank > 500 and Rank < 1000
Segment 4: Rank > 1000
```

Any ideas how I can go about creating segments like this?

The only options I get are:

```
Is
Is Not
Contains
Does Not Contain
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way? Just throw all values into "is" and concatenate by OR.

I don't know customer segmentation but for salesrule you can have (equals or) greater/less than, so you only need two rules to build what you need.